# Can formaldehyde be stored at a higher temperature than room temperature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, temperature, reactivity

I have studied that formaldehyde stored at temperature lower than room temperature convert into 1,3,5-oxane. So, it's not stored at colder temperatures.

But my question is - Can a similar degrading reaction happen if methanal is stored at temperature higher than room temperature?

Comment: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100260a032

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trimerization of formaldehyde can happen at high temperatures, but appear to require catalysts. There is a [patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US6313323) for synthesizing 1,3,5-trioxide at high temperature. This patent uses phosphoric acid catalysts.
According to the patent:

> The process of the invention is advantageously carried out at reaction temperatures of from 80 to 160° C., preferably from **90 to 145° C**., at an inlet partial pressure of the formaldehyde of from 0.5 to 5 bar absolute, preferably from 0.5 to 2 bar, and at an inlet concentration of formaldehyde of from 1 to 100% by volume, preferably from 20 to 100% by volume

There is also an early study which explored the kinetics of the reaction but for a different catalyst. In ["Vapour-phase trimerization of formaldehyde to trioxane catalysed by 1-vanado-11-molybdophosphoric acid"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926860X96002864) by Kern and Emig, they use a molybdophosphoric acid catalyst. They used a tube reactor and varied the temperature from 
**102.5 to 110° C**. According to their study:

> The 
>   conversion 
>   observed 
>   increases 
>   extremely 
>   with 
>   decreasing 
>   temperature.

However, they comment that

> the 
>   temperature 
>   dependence 
>   cannot 
>   be 
>   attributed 
>   to 
>   thermodynamic 
>   effects 
>   only. 
>   It 
>   has 
>   to 
>   be 
>   related 
>   to 
>   the 
>   properties 
>   of 
>   the 
>   heteropoly 
>   compound.

Another study is "Synthesis of Trioxane Using Heteropolyacids as
Catalysts" by Mazamoto et al. Their process uses heteropolyacids as catalysts and they were able to obtain a conversion % of 22.9 at **110° C**. Where 
$$\text{Conversion %}=\frac{3[\text{trioxane}]+2[\text{methyl formate}]+[\text{methylal}]}{[\text{feed formaldehyde}]}\cdot 100$$